# how to Highlight read only Text Area based on deletes from another of same text area?

Tags: html, css, angular, textarea, highlight

I have two text area with same content.One is read only text area and other is editable text area. When a user deletes any text using 'delete' or 'backspace' or 'ctrl+x'then that data need to be highlighted in read only text area. The highlight should always show up the difference between read only text area and editable text area. Any idea how to achieve this goal. Have tried few options nothing is working as expected. Experts help is greatly appreciated.

All this happening in one component.

HTML code:

```
      <label class="edit-title">Topic Description (System, Read-Only)</label>
      <textarea rows="14" cols="60" class="description edit-text-area" [(ngModel)]="data.topicDescLong" readonly></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="topic-section topic-divider">
      <label class="edit-title">Topic Description for Presentation</label>
      <textarea rows="14" cols="60" class="description edit-text-area" [(ngModel)]="data.editedTopicDescLong" (ngModelChange)="onEditLongTopicDescChange()"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Component Code:

```
onEditLongTopicDescChange(){
  if(this.data.editedTopicDescLong.trim().length === 0 )
  {
    this.isSaveDisabled = true;
    this.isSubmitDisabled = true;
  }else{
    if(this.orginalEditTopicLongDesc != this.data.editedTopicDescLong)
    {
      this.isSaveDisabled = false;
      this.isSubmitDisabled = false;
    }
    else{
      this.isSaveDisabled = true;
      this.isSubmitDisabled = true;
    }
  }
  }
```

When user Delete any text using 'delete' or 'backspace' or 'ctrl+x'
Then the selected text should be removed from the editable section
and highlight the deleted part on read only section.  [Sample Image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQizQ.png)
Left is readonly text area and right is editable area.

Comment: To my understanding, diff checking is a nontrivial problem, which is why diff checkers break text files up line-by-line and highlight the changed lines instead of detecting changes at a character-level of granularity.

Comment: @KeenanDiggs thanks for reply. Do we have any thrid party library to do the same. To check and highlight at line level.

Comment: Diff checking tools have been around since the 70s, but they typically compare the difference between 2 file states. So at best, out of the box you could only show the difference between the original document and the current state. It would get trickier to show multiple state transitions (Consider that if user is changing a lot of things, that could be counter-intuitive to see multiple colors/levels of changes).